# Where can I find rules for explosives or fireworks?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

I noticed that there is no mention of fireworks or explosives in the *Player's Handbook*.

Is there somewhere I could look for common rules and uses for fireworks/explosives in D&D 5E or previous versions?  Or do I just make this stuff up with my DM?

Comment: do you look for official material only, or is homebrew/UA okay too?

Answer (score 16):

Pages **267-268** of the 5th Edition **Dungeon Master's Guide** contains rules for firearms, explosives, etc. at renaissance, modern, and futuristic tech levels. No specific mention of fireworks, but you can probably work with what's already there.